# About the extension of derivatives over fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory

In commutative algebra I found the following problem:

Let $K\leq Q\leq L$ be three fields and assume $Q/K$ and $L/K$ are extensions with trascendence degree $1$. Then there is a bijection between $K$-derivations of $Q$  and $K$-derivations of $L$ iff $L/Q$ is a separable extension.

Of course any derivation on $L$ induces a derivation on $Q$ by restriction, but I dont know how we can extend a derivation from $Q$ to $L$. My problem is that I dont have any idea on how to relate derivations with a separable extension, I dont see the connection. Also, for the other implication, I think I have to show that if the extension is not separable there exists a counterexample of a derivation wich cannot be extended.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98263/derivations-and-separability-of-field-extensions?rq=1) helpful? The part in boldface seems to address your question.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks